# Why do std::ranges::binary_search and std::binary_search produce different results for the same input?

Tags: c++, c++20, std, binary-search, std-ranges

I don't understand why `std::ranges::binary_search` works different than `std::binary_search`. For example, this kind of code:

```cpp
std::vector<int> A = { 0, 10, 12, 30 };
std::cout << std::ranges::binary_search(A.begin(), A.end(), 28) << std::endl;
std::cout << std::binary_search(A.begin(), A.end(), 28) << std::endl;
```

This outputs:

```
1
0
```

Is somebody can to explain that?

I've tried changing type inside of vector, and I checked ranges version without iterators. Of course I checked also a documentation in cppreference, but none of this helps.

Comment: This seems to be [a bug in libc++](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/61160) that I reported and [has been fixed in clang-16](https://godbolt.org/z/x38Wv69af).

Comment: Should the ranges version take a begin and end, or a range?

Comment: @JosephLarson typically std::ranges algorithms have overloads both for a range and a pair of iterators.